# ORA-001722 Invalid Number when insert in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE the_user( Name VARCHAR(40) not null,
    Address VARCHAR(255) not null,
    Delivery_address VARCHAR(255),
    Email VARCHAR(25) not null,
    Phone INTEGER not null,
    Status INTEGER not null,
    Password VARCHAR(25) not null, 
    DOB DATE not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (Email),
    FOREIGN KEY (Status) REFERENCES User_Status (Status_Id),
    CONSTRAINT check_Password CHECK (Password > 4)
);


INSERT  INTO  the_user VALUES  (
    'Pergrin Took',
    '12 Bag end, hobbiton, The Shire, Eriador',
    'The address, Dublin',
    'ptook@lotr.com',
    '8679046',
    '001',
    'treebeard',
    TO_DATE('2013/11/04 14:11:34', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
);
```

I have the above database in Oracle but when I try to run the insert command I get an ORA-1722 error, Invalid Number. There is a entry in the user_status table which corresponds to the 1 in the insert.

I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Numbers must not be enclosed in single quotes: `'8679046'` is a string value, `8679046`  is a number. And `'001'` is not a number either.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are not a problem - it will be converted implicitly to numbers as far as they are valid.

Check your constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT check_Password CHECK (Password > 4)
```

Here you try to compare string and number -> in this comparison Oracle always tries to cast both as numbers -> password fails and you see an error.

Try to use instead of password e.g. '55' and you will see the row is inserted.

Perhaps you wanted to do this?

```
CONSTRAINT check_Password CHECK (length(Password) > 4)
```